# How can I cut a variable with subprocces?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

```
out=subprocess.check_output("""cat /etc/passwd""", universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
  for line in out.splitlines():
        elem=subprocess.check_output(["echo", "line", "|", "cut", "-d:", "-f1"], 
                                     universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
        lboxS.insert(END,elem)
```

Comment: What variable are you referring to? What do you want to cut? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @DanielBecerra : In your command, a literal `|` would be passed to `echo` as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> elem=subprocess.check_output(["echo", "line", "|", "cut", "-d:", "-f1"], universal_newlines=True, shell=True)
> ```

If you use `shell=True`, you have to pass a single string for *args* (as you did with `out`):

```
elem = subprocess.check_output("echo '"+line+"'|cut -d: -f1", text=True, shell=True).rstrip()
```

or

```
elem = subprocess.check_output("echo '%s'|cut -d: -f1"%line, text=True, shell=True).rstrip()
```

or

```
elem = subprocess.check_output(f"echo '{line}'|cut -d: -f1", text=True, shell=True).rstrip()
```